# r listfiles 3 versus 4 conditions

Tags: r

I want to search on four conditions in some file names. Here's how I am trying that.

I have a couple of test files with the following names

```
mpi-esm1-2-hr_r1i1p1f1_w5e5_ssp126_hurs_global_daily_2041_2050.nc
mpi-esm1-2-hr_r1i1p1f1_w5e5_ssp126_hurs_global_daily_2051_2060.nc
```

I use this approach to construct a pattern

```
modelChoice.lower <- "mpi-esm1-2-hr"
startYear = 2041
climVar <- "_hurs_"
sspChoice <- "ssp126"
pattern1 <- paste0(modelChoice.lower, ".+", climVar, ".+", sspChoice, ".+", startYear)
pattern2 <- paste0(modelChoice.lower, ".+", climVar, ".+", startYear + 10)
ff1 <- list.files(locOfFiles, pattern = pattern1, full.names = TRUE)
ff2 <- list.files(locOfFiles, pattern = pattern2, full.names = TRUE)
pattern1


> pattern1
[1] "mpi-esm1-2-hr.+_hurs_.+ssp126.+2041"
> pattern2
[1] "mpi-esm1-2-hr.+_hurs_.+2051"
> ff1
character(0)
> ff2
[1] "climdata/mpi-esm1-2-hr_r1i1p1f1_w5e5_ssp126_hurs_global_daily_2051_2060.nc"
```

Is there some way to get pattern1 to work?

Comment: Check the order, according to your test files `sspChoice` should precede `climVar`

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways to get the match to work:

If you use the following:

```
pattern1 <- paste0(modelChoice.lower, ".+", sspChoice, "+", climVar, ".+",startYear)
```

or (probably preferentially)

```
pattern1 <- paste0(modelChoice.lower, ".+", sspChoice, ".*", climVar, ".+",startYear)
```

The problem here is the regex pasted between sspChoice and climVar.  The '+' requires 1 or more characters to exist.  Since the strings for sspChoice and climVar were directly adjacent with zero characters between them, the code did not find a match.  If you use '*' in place of the '+', you allow for "zero or more" as opposed to "one or more" characters to exist in that space.

You could also take the underscores out of your `climVar`, but depending on your files this could lead to some matches you're not looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the comments put me on the right track. Thanks! It turns out that order matters and ".*" are needed. So I am using

```
pattern1 <- paste0(modelChoice.lower, ".*", sspChoice, ".*", climVar, ".*",  startYear)
```